# How can I SELECT a result set of data from a single table with one of the columns coming from the SUM of a column in a different table?

Tags: sql

So let's say I want 5 columns total in my result set, for example:

```
Name, Date, Color, Price, TotalSales
```

Name, Date, Color, and Price are all stored in a single table so I will just get every row from that table.

```
SELECT * FROM AwesomeStuff
```

However, TotalSales needs to be calculated from the SUM of values in another table, and the values that needed to be combined must match up with the ID of the row from the AwesomeStuff table.

```
SELECT SUM(SalePrice) FROM AwesomeSales
```

Each row in the AwesomeSales table has an ID that matches a single item in the AwesomeStuff table. So I want to add up all the SalePrice values into a single column and match it up with the correct row in the AwesomeStuff query so I get back the single result set.

How does this work? Along with the query, can you explain what SQL is doing in plain english so I can understand how to write this type of SELECT again in the future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform a `GROUP BY` operation to group the results per "AwesomeStuff" item:

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    A.Date,
    A.Color,
    A.Price,
    SUM(S.SalePrice) AS TotalSales
FROM
    AwesomeStuff A
INNER JOIN
    AwesomeSales S
ON
    S.AwesomeStuffId = A.Id
GROUP BY
    A.Name,
    A.Date,
    A.Color,
    A.Price
```

Comment: What if there are multiple AwesomeStuff records with the same name, date, color and price?

Comment: @MarkBannister - it seems unlikely given the context, but if all of those details were the same the report would be no more useful with the total sales on two lines or one line. If Ryan thinks this is likely, he could add the primary key to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
    t.name, 
    t.date, 
    t.color, 
    t.price, 
    a.TotalSales
from awesomestuff t
inner join
(
    select id, sum(saleprice) as TotalSales
    from awesomesales
    group by id
)a
on t.id = a.id
```

What this does is calculates the `SUM()` based on each `id`.  And then with an inner join it creates the relationship for the `TotalSales` per `id` to show in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL to do what you want is:

```
select   AwesomeStuff.Name,
         AwesomeStuff.Date,
         AwesomeStuff.Color,
         AwesomeStuff.Price,
         AwesomeStuff.TotalSales,
         TotalSales.Price
from     AwesomeStuff
join    (select   AwesomeSales.id,
                  sum(AwesomeSales.SalePrice) As Price
         from     AwesomeSales
         group by id) As TotalSales
on       TotalSales.id = AwesomeStuff.id;
```

<strike>I will update this post after lunch with an English explanation.</strike>

**English** You aggregate the sale prices, taking the sum, grouped by their ID. This is what the inline view (sub-query) does: we include the ID because we need to use it in the join. That is we join your `AwesomeStuff` table with the inline view of sales (aliased as `TotalSales`, as we refer to it later), match them by ID -- as this is the primary key -- and then select all the fields (including the calculated sum, which we have aliased as `Price`) together.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery if your Database supports it:

```
SELECT stuff.Name, stuff.Date, stuff.Color, stuff.Price, sales.total 
FROM AwesomeStuff AS stuff,
     (SELECT STUFF_ID, SUM(SalePrice) AS total
      FROM AwesomeSales
      GROUP BY STUFF_ID) AS sales
where stuff.ID = sales.STUFF_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
       a.Name,
       a.Date,
       a.Color,
       a.Price,
       SUM(s.SalesPrice)

FROM   AwesomeStuff as a
       INNER JOIN AwesomeSales as s on a.ID = s.AwesomestuffID

GROUP BY a.Name, a.Date, a.Color, a.Price
```

In plain English, what you are doing is saying give me all the unique combinations of name, date, color and price from your stuff table and a sum of all the sales from the sales table.  This assumes that each ID in the stuff table represents a unique combination of name, date, color and price.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT A.Id, -- not required in select for query to work - included for clarity
       max(A.Name),
       max(A.Date),
       max(A.Color),
       max(A.Price),
       SUM(S.SalePrice) AS TotalSales
FROM AwesomeStuff A
LEFT JOIN AwesomeSales S ON S.AwesomeStuffId = A.Id
GROUP BY A.Id
```

By joining AwesomeStuff to AwesomeSales on the product's unique ID, you will get a row returned for every sale of every product - since you only want one row per product, you need to group by the product's unique ID. (The SUM function should be self-explanatory.)

Unfortunately, most forms of SQL will not allow you to include unaggregated values in a grouped query, even where these are functionally dependant on one of the values that is being grouped - as in this query. This is why name, date, color and price have all been MAXed.

A left join ensures that records on the left-hand side of the join (here, AwesomeStuff) will be returned even if there are no corresponding records on the right-hand side of the join (AwesomeSales). In other words, this version of the query will include products that have had no sales.